# FileNotFoundError:when trying to replace existing csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, file-not-found

I can't seem to get this code that usually runs in another script to run properly in a new script. At the end of the code it will look up and see if the file exists and if it does it will replace it and change the downloaded file name to a specified file name but I keep getting an error. Any idea what I might be missing?

here is the code

```
database = "E:\Stock Database\Historical Data\Historical Stock List\\"

chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs               = {'download.default_directory': database}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name='prefs', value= prefs)
stocks              = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\Python Programs\chromedriver", chrome_options = chrome_options)

#Website
stocks.get(universe_data_site)

#Navigate Web Page
stocks.find_element_by_css_selector('#ui-id-4').click()
stocks.find_element_by_css_selector('#stocks > a.blue_button.factbutton').click()
stocks.find_element_by_css_selector('body > a:nth-child(3)').click()

#Download and renaiming of File
filename = 'allstocks.csv'

#removes existing file if already exists
if os.path.exists(r"%s%s"%(database,filename)) is True:
         os.remove(r"%s%s"%(database,filename))
         os.rename(r"%s"%database+ "stockfactsheet.csv ",r"%s%s"%(database,filename))
else:
        os.rename(r"%s"%database+ "stockfactsheet.csv ",r"%s%s"%(database,filename))
```

Here is the error I get

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-6093fcfb1ff0> in <module>()
     17          os.rename(r"%s"%database+ "stockfactsheet.csv",r"%s%s"%(database,filename))
 18 else:
---> 19         os.rename(r"%s"%database+ "stockfactsheet.csv,r"%s%s"%(database,filename))

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock Liststockfactsheet.csv ' -> 'E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock Listallstocks.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message doesn't have (a) backslash(es) after the parent directory:

```
'E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock Liststockfactsheet.csv '
                                                           ^
                                                           here
```

I think that may be caused by a missing quote after "stockfactsheet.csv" in the line:

```
os.rename(r"%s"%database+ "stockfactsheet.csv,r"%s%s"%(database,filename))
                                             ^
                                             here
```

Additionally, there is a space at the end of `stockfactsheet.csv`, which seems to be coming from your first call to `os.rename`:

```
os.rename(r"%s"%database+ "stockfactsheet.csv ",r"%s%s"%(database,filename))
                                             ^
                                             here
```

If you're not using an IDE with context highlighting (I would recommend PyCharm), you really should be - I saw the quote issue right away once it was highlighted by my IDE.

Comment: Can you edit your OP to reflect what you tried, and what error you're getting?

Comment: database       = "E:\Stock Database\Historical Data\Historical Stock List\\"

Comment: Are you sure your change is giving *exactly* the same error with backslashes missing after the enclosing folder, or does the error message now have a path with backslashes there? See my edits - there's another problem.

Comment: I see what you are saying with the space. Made the change but still getting the error. I'm starting to think it might be when the file downloads. When completed it have file name stockfacksheet.csv but when it's in the process of doing the DL it has the name stockfactsheet.csv.crdownload. Perhaps this is causing the issue. If you know of have a link for how I can get the proper file name before the DL of the DL that would perhaps help?

Comment: From the error message it seems like `'E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock Liststockfactsheet.csv '` is a symbolic link that goes nowhere.

Comment: @Try - if you place a file in "Historical Stock List" called "stockfactsheet.csv" do you still get the error?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I did what you mentioned yet I still get an error of the file downloads as "stockfactsheet(1).csv" or "stockfactsheet(2).csv" and so on

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the .crdownload file then.

Comment: Another problem I found, which makes sense with the missing backslashes: you have a missing quote. See my update. Are you using an IDE with highlighting? You might not be seeing these issues.